# Combine few grok into one

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the log entry and the grok pattern as below.

Log:

```
2017-04-11 18:31:41,938 | INFO | 195 | Process | Bundle Name | logStr: GUID: dl99X/WeN77E2SmyjH9uS1Fy+EDvFQ5R_939bae | ReferenceID: 20170411183141500676 | InstanceID: 70411183141906430422429270016 | ChannelID: EXAMPLE | System: EXAMPLE | ServiceName: EXAMPLE | InvocationPoint: inbound

2017-04-11 18:31:42,743 | INFO | 193 | API | Bundle Name | Outbound Message | RESPONSE=[GUID=[dl99X/WeN77E2SmyjH9uS1Fy+EDvFQ5R_939bae], InstanceID=[70411183141906430422429270016], logStr=[GUID: dl99X/WeN77E2SmyjH9uS1Fy+EDvFQ5R_939bae | ReferenceID: 20170411183141500676 | InstanceID: 70411183141906430422429270016 | ChannelID: EXAMPLE | System: EXAMPLE | ServiceName: EXAMPLE | InvocationPoint: inbound
```

Grok pattern:

```
grok {
#grok general pattern
match => {
"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{DATA:thread}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{DATA:serviceName}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{DATA:bundle}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logdetails}"
}
}   
#Grok to get GUID
grok {
match => {
"logdetails" => "(?<=GUID:).%{DATA:guid}(?=\s)" 
}
}
#Grok to get ChannelID
grok {
match => {
"logdetails" => "(?<=ChannelID:).%{DATA:channelID}(?=\s)"   
}
}
#Grok to get ReferenceID
grok {
match => {
"logdetails" => "(?<=ReferenceID:).%{DATA:referenceID}(?=\s)"   
}
}
```

I have few separate grok to just get the GUID, ChannelID and ReferenceID. 
Is there any way to combine the groks into one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to know the types of logs you're dealing with, but what I'll do when there are too many types to worry about (but they remain in the same format):

1. Determine the base format
2. Treat everything after base as the "msg" or payload.
3. Parse the payload with the fields you are looking for.

Each of your messages have the base format of `timestamp | loglevel | thread`:

```
LINE %{BASE}\s?\|\s?%{GREEDYDATA:msg}

# Patterns
BASE %{CUSTTIME:timestamp}\s?\|\s?%{WORD:loglevel}\s?\|\s?%{NONNEGINT:thread}
CUSTTIME %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND},%{MILLI}
MILLI (?:([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0))
```

Then you can just add the patterns for the fields you're looking for in the same pattern file, since all of the values are very similar to key=value, but instead with colons:

```
COMMAVALUE (\s?(.*?(?=\s\w+:|$))\s?)

# Fields
GUID GUID:%{COMMAVALUE:guid}
CHANNELID ChannelID:%{COMMAVALUE:channel_id}
REFERENCEID ReferenceID:%{COMMAVALUE:reference_id}
```

So you can use two adjacent grok filters to do this, one to extract the `msg` payload, and another to extract the fields from said msg.

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir   => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
        match => { "message" => "%{LINE}" }
    }
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
        break_on_match => false
        match => [
            "msg", "%{GUID}",
            "msg", "%{CHANNELID}",
            "msg", "%{REFERENCEID}"
        ]
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```